# Understand output of the while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
def loop_mystery_exam1(i, j):
    while i != 0 and j != 0:
        i = i //j
        j = (j - 1) // 2
        print(str(i) + " " + str(j) + " ", end='')
    print(str(i))
    print(i + j)
    
loop_mystery_exam1(80, 9)
```

I get this output:

```
8 4 2 1 2 0 2

2
```

Why there are only 2 outputs? I think there should be 3, since there are 3 print statements.

Comment: "I am unable to understand why there are only 2 outputs, when there should be 3 (since there are 3 print statements)" There should be **5** outputs - it *does not matter* how many places the code says `print`, what matters is *how many times those calls are made*. There **are** 5 outputs, so there is no error. Just because something is on the same line, doesn't make it the same output. Also, `print` is **not** a "statement" in 3.x. Please try to read the documentation for `print`, and make sure you understand what the `end = ''` part does.

Comment: Also: please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We are *not interested* in your level of skill (and it will be apparent from the question anyway). We *are* interested in a *clear, specific, directly asked* question. I [edit]ed the post to show how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

Python's `print` method has the `end` with the default value of `\n` which means a new line, you can check it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

That means you are overwriting this default behavior forcing your code to print i and j in the same line until `print(str(i))` which will break the line.

If you are coding in an IDE, add a breakpoint in the while line and you will see it.

A suggestion here would be to remove the `end=''` of the first print, or write as the following:

```py
def loop_mystery_exam1(i, j):
    while i != 0 and j != 0:
        i = i // j
        j = (j - 1) // 2
        print(f"i={i} ; j={j}")
    print(i)
    print(i + j)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first print statement runs three times. The first time it prints `8 4` , then `2 1` , then `2 0` . Each time, there is a trailing space, but no newline.

The second print statement prints `2` and then a newline.

The third print statement prints `0` and then a newline.